# python dynamic test generation

Tags: python, unit-testing, nose

I've a base class that yields test cases. Concrete implementations of the class register tests. Since nose only supports test generation via yield for test functions (not classes) I want a class decorator that applies the necessary function wrapping.

NOTE: the reason why I need to yield test cases is that the test class needs to do some initialization that cannot be run in setUp.

Below is a minimal example that shows the expected behavior, however, it only works if the `make_generator` decorator is **in** the current module - when I move it to a separate module no tests are yielded. Can anybody tell me why this happens?

```
def make_generator(cls):
    """returns a function that instantiates ``cls`` and yields tests. """
    def generator():
        obj = cls()
        for t in obj:
            yield t

    generator.__name__ = 'test_%s' % cls.__name__
    return generator


def register(func):
    """Set _check attr of ``func``. """
    func._check = True
    return func


class BaseMixin(object):

    def __init__(self):
        """Register check handlers. """
        self.check_handlers = []
        attrs = (attr for attr in dir(self) if not attr.startswith('__'))
        for attr in attrs:
            func = getattr(self, attr)
            if getattr(func, '_check', False):
                self.check_handlers.append(attr)

    def __iter__(self):
        """Generate tests for registered handlers. """
        # do stuff
        args = []
        for check in self.check_handlers:
            func = getattr(self, check)
            yield func, args


@make_generator
class ConcreteTest(BaseMixin):

    @register
    def check_foobar(self, args):
        assert False
```

Comment: I'm a little confused why you're making a generator instead of just using nose's duck typing schema? Why make your life harder?

Comment: what do you mean by nose's duck typing schema exactly?

Comment: I mean declaring all your tests along the lines of `def test_foo():` `def test_baz():`. Are you using nose?

Comment: the problem is that I need to do some initialization before running the tests and I cannot do that in a setUp (there are multiple setUp stages and specific tests should be run after each stage)

Answer (score 0):

I found out why no test are yielded if I move the `make_generator` decorator to a different module.

make_generator will return a function, the `__module__` attribute of this function will be the module in which `make_generator` is defined - which is not the tested module and thus nose will not run the generated test function.

If I set the `__module__` attribute of the returned function it works fine::

```
def make_generator(cls):
"""returns a function that instantiates ``cls`` and yields tests. """
def generator():
    obj = cls()
    for t in obj:
        yield t

generator.__name__ = 'test_%s' % cls.__name__
# set to the same module as test case so that nose runs it
generator.__module__ = cls.__module__
return generator
```